# Fantasy book about Grendel type character

Tags: story-identification, novel, medieval

Looking for a book written in the last 15 years (probably). Set in a medieval / Viking time but not necessarily our timeline.  Main character is similar to Grendel in appearance: apelike, clawed hands, fangs, dark leathery skin. He is the last of his family/race, who are very violent.  Possibly capable of hibernation or very long lived.  The other main character is a human female who is a nun(?) who encounters the Grendel, is taken prisoner, then becomes a sidekick in the Grendel's quest for vengeance on somebody? There is travel in an open boat similar to a Viking long boat through stormy seas.

Comment: Not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grendel_(novel)?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, given the plot described by OP, then no. Very much not